# How to Make array from_date to to_date using CarbonPeriod and Match another date is exist in array or not in php , Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

i have two date :
$from = 2022-11-01
$to = 2022-11-05

now , i wanna create a array like this :
$date = ['2022-11-01','2022-11-02','2022-11-03','2022-11-04','2022-11-05']

and now check '2022-11-03' is exist in $date array or not.

alrady use :
`$date = Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($from, $to);`

```
if(in_array('2022-11-03', $date)){
    echo "Got it";
}
```

**#But Still not Work**

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Your approach would work like this: $carbonArray = iterator_to_array(CarbonPeriod::create($from, $to));
if( in_array(carbon::parse('2022-11-03'), $carbonArray))...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just check if the CarbonPeriod contains the date you check:

```
$from = '2022-11-01';
$to = '2022-11-05';
$date = Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($from, $to);
if ($date->contains('2022-11-03')) {
    echo 'Got it';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It was asked for a solution with CarbonPeriod. However, if you only want to check if a date is between $from and $to, between is the better choice.

```
$from = "2022-11-01";
$to = "2022-11-05";
$check = "2022-11-03";
if(Carbon::parse($check)->between($from,$to)){
  echo $check.' is between '.$from.' and '.$to;
} else {
  echo $check.' is not between '.$from.' and '.$to;
}
```

[Try Carbon](https://try-carbon.herokuapp.com/?hide-output-gutter%26output-left-padding=10&theme=tomorrow_night&border=none&radius=4&v-padding=15&input=%24from%20%3D%20%222022-11-01%22%3B%0D%0A%24to%20%3D%20%222022-11-05%22%3B%0D%0A%24check%20%3D%20%222022-11-03%22%3B%0D%0Aif%28Carbon%3A%3Aparse%28%24check%29-%3Ebetween%28%24from%2C%24to%29%29%7B%0D%0A%20%20echo%20%24check.%27%20is%20between%20%27.%24from.%27%20and%20%27.%24to%3B%0D%0A%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20echo%20%24check.%27%20is%20not%20between%20%27.%24from.%27%20and%20%27.%24to%3B%0D%0A%7D&token=live-editor-120)

If the data is all in the format yyyy-mm-dd, a simple string comparison is sufficient.

```
$from = "2022-11-01";
$to = "2022-11-05";
$check = "2022-11-03";
if($from <= $check AND $check <= $to) {
  echo $check.' is between '.$from.' and '.$to;
} else {
  echo $check.' is not between '.$from.' and '.$to;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/A1IBh

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question it could be that you aren't using `parse` method to parse dates, so this could be the problem.

```
        $from = "2022-11-01";
        $to = "2022-11-05";
        $dates = CarbonPeriod::create(
            Carbon::parse($from),
            Carbon::parse($to),
        );
        $dateArray = [];
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $dateArray[] = $date->toDateString();
        }
```

Here, `$dateArray` provides you with the dates array.

Furthermore the if section works correctly for the above solution:

```
if(in_array('2022-11-03', $date)){
    echo "Got it";
}
```

Comment: it will work as well. for code simplicity, we can use 1st solution

Comment: That's right Even I would recommend @Ross_102's answer.